# (R) column mean works with one command but not with another

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, na, summarize

I've imported this dataset (available [here](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/raw/master/data/OxCGRT_latest.csv)) as a csv file into R:

```
oxcgrt <- read_csv("C:/Users/Local/Documents/COVID19datasets/OxCGRT/OxCGRT_latest.csv")
```

> Parsed with column specification: cols(   .default = col_double(),
> CountryName = col_character(),   CountryCode = col_character(),
> M1_Wildcard = col_logical() ) See spec(...) for full column
> specifications.

I used `summarize()` on variable "E1_Income support":

```
summarize(oxcgrt, inc_sup = mean("E1_Income support", na.rm = TRUE))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 x 1
>   inc_sup
>     <dbl>
> 1      NA
> Warning message:
> In mean.default("E1_Income support", na.rm = TRUE) :
>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> ```

The issue could not be NA values in the variable since I specified "na.rm = TRUE". However another command does it:

```
mean(oxcgrt$"E1_Income support", na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 0.4758057
```

Variable "E1_Income support" is not numeric:

```
is.numeric("E1_Income support")
# [1] FALSE
```

Does anyone know why the latter can calculate the mean but not the former?
Thank you

P.S.: the data is updated daily, so variable mean should be slightly different from the mean I reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obtaining that error because you are writing `"E1_Income support"`. Inside `dplyr` statements, this is considered just as a string and does **not** refer to the column of the dataframe. To do that, you should delete the double quotes.

In this particular case, you actually need to use backticks `` because there is a whitespace in the column name you are selecting. Otherwise backticks are not needed.

```
summarize(oxcgrt, inc_sup = mean(`E1_Income support`, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#   inc_sup
#     <dbl>
# 1   0.477
```